# Load method after a page is loaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a method which is downloading an XML and sorting it's data into `collectionA`. I then have `collectionA` split into 2 smaller collections, `collectionB` & `collectionC` which populate 2 lists. Now the issue I am having is that the method which is populating and splitting `collectionA` is being completed before `collectionA` has the time to populate itself.

How would I go around making the `collectionB` & `collectionC` wait until `collectionA` is populated?

Method populating `collectionA`

```
    public void downloadXML(bool data)
            {
                if (data == false)
                {
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
                    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ec.urbentom.co.uk/studentAppData.xml"));
                }            
            }

            private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                setupDictionary(); 
                MainPage page = new MainPage();
                if (e.Error != null)
                    return;
                XElement xmlitems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                List<XElement> elements = xmlitems.Descendants("item").ToList();

                List<StudentGuideModel> moveItems = new List<StudentGuideModel>();
                foreach (XElement c in elements)
                {
                    StudentGuideModel _item = new StudentGuideModel();

                    _item.Title = c.Element("Title").Value;
                    _item.Description = c.Element("Description").Value;
                    _item.Phone = c.Element("Phone").Value;
                    _item.Email = c.Element("Email").Value;
                    _item.Category = c.Element("Category").Value;
                    _item.Image = c.Element("Image").Value;
                    _item.SmallInfo = c.Element("SmallInfo").Value;
                    _item.Image = getImage(_item.Image);
                    allData.Add(_item);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Download Complete", "Loaded", MessageBoxButton.OK);                                                          
            }
```

Method populating `collectionB` & `collectionC`

```
public ObservableCollection<StudentGuideModel> splitCategories(string catName)
{
    ObservableCollection<StudentGuideModel> catItems = new ObservableCollection<StudentGuideModel>();
    foreach (var item in allData)
    {
        if (item.Category == catName)
        {
            catItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return catItems;
}
```

Population of lists using `collectionB` & `collectionC`

```
faciliiesList.ItemsSource = App.getControl.splitCategories("Facilities");
contactPanel.ItemsSource = App.getControl.splitCategories("Contacts");
```

Comment: Please add the code which calls tge population of a b and c so we can see why you say a finishes before you're done populating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you call downloadXML first and then splitCategories second in the page_Loaded event handler. (btw, you should follow C# naming conventions, your methods should be DownloadXML and SplitCategories).

Because your webclient subscribes to the DownloadStringCompleted event, your splitCategories probably begins to populate B and C before the string is downloaded. I would suggest you get the HTTP Client libraries from NuGet (Microsoft.Net.Http is the id on NuGet). The HTTPClient uses the async/await framework and it will do the job for you. Here's sample code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
string downloadedString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ec.urbentom.co.uk/studentAppData.xml");
// Populate A here
// PopulateB here
```

Note, you will have to add the async keyword to the Loaded event handler.